# How to switch out of RealVNC VNC Viewer fullscreen mode with single shortcut?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, vnc, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I would like to switch out of `VNC Viewer` with keyboard, leaving it in fullscreen mode.

Is it possible?

I don't want to press `F8` then use Alt-TAB or mouse (two shortcuts) to leave and then use another two shortcuts to return. Need just one shortcut, like `Ctrl`-`Left` and `Ctrl`-`Right` on Macos.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.. Like you mentioned, you need to setup a macro that presses both `F8` + `ALT` + `TAB`.  Microsoft has a software called **Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center**,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2

From Microsoft's documentation on Mouse and Keyboard center, follow these instructions:

1. Using the keyboard that you want to configure, start Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.
2. Select a key in the Key Settings List.
3. In the list under the key that you want to reassign, select Macro.
4. Click Create a new Macro.
5. An empty macro is created and added to the macro list.
6. In the Name box, type the name of the new macro. Click in Editor, enter your macro. You can record events such as keystrokes, mouse clicks, and delays between actions. You cannot capture mouse movement or actions performed through macros assigned to reassignable keys.
7. In the Available Macros list, make sure that the new macro is selected.\

Hope this helps.